# OOP desing, Java Swing, chess game, instanceof

Tags: java, swing, oop, instanceof

OK, I'm in the process of making a simple java swing chess game. This question is more about OOP design then Java Swing.

I have the following:

- I have a Panel class that implements JPanel.
- I then have an abstract class Piece that extends from my Panel class
- Then I have my classes for the different Pieces: Pawn, King, Bishop etc that extend from my Pieces class

In my main ChessGame Class:

- I am using an array of Panel to store the layout of my board
- So the array will store, Panel objects, for board places with no pieces on it.
- And it will store, the subclasses such as Pawn, Queen, Bishop etc (board places with pieces)

So, the top left square (0,0) maps to myArray[0][0]

My problem is that, to check if the place is empty or has chess pieces in it I have to use:

```
        if(panels[x][y] instanceof Piece){
            ((Piece)panels[x][y]).makeMove();
        }
```

What I'm asking is this terrible design? I know I should try and stay away from instanceof.
What would be a better approach?

Thanks.

Comment: You can fill `null` to tell there is no Piece there, or you can create new class `Empty` and inherit from Panel and then yes, instanceof is good way around.

Comment: @kajacx make that a answer. It is perfect.

Comment: @kajacx Thanks for the quick reply. The panel objects provide functionality, they make up the empty board places. So, I'm not sure if null would work. My Panel class is my Empty class is it not? It just creates empty places on the board.

Comment: You could generate a model in which the position within the grid was stored aginst the piece.  So you could do a "isEmpty" check by simply checking the model to see if the grid position existed.  For example, you could use a `Map` as the base model, keyed against a `Grid`/`Cell` object.  This would also mean that you would only need to iterate the "model" and it would only return relevant information (no empty cells) when updating the view, for example.

Comment: You could also add a `boolean isOccupied()` to `Panel`. `return false` in Panel, but override (and `return true`) in `Piece`.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't combine the Model code (Piece) with the view code (JPanels).   If you ever want to change how the board is displayed you have to change how pieces are stored!

A better design might be to separate Piece from JPanels.  Then you can use a single JPanel to display a matrix of Pieces : `Pieces[8][8]`.

**My problem is that, to check if the place is empty or has chess pieces in it I have to use:**

If you use a matrix, you can just have a null cell or use the `Null Object` Pattern to have an "empty" piece.

**EDIT**

Each cell in the piece matrix is a square in the board so `piece[0][0]` would be the top corner of the board (A8).

To paint the board your `paintComponent()` method would have to iterate over this matrix and draw each cell appropriately.  There are several ways to implement this:

1. You would need to do a similar instanceof check to draw each type of piece differently
2. Make a new intermediate "paint strategy" object using the strategy pattern.  This may require a matrix of strategy objects instead of piece objects. You may still need to do instance of checks, but maybe only the once to create the strategy objects.

Comment: I agree, not sure if I understand what you mean in terms of the approach? So an int or char array maybe to store, where each piece is on the board? Then add JPanels to match the setup of the Pieces array?

Comment: OK thanks. I will give it a go. So, you reckon drawing the board is a better approach than using 64 JPanels?

Comment: Yes.  You would still have to draw in the JPanels anyway.

Comment: I was just using a JLabel with an image of the correct Piece inside the JPanels.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting panel to 8x8 smaller panels, you must draw the board and the pieces on a canvas. Later the players will eventually be dragging to move pieces on board. Also you could look for Bitboard presentation in chess game, although this presentation is only required for chess engines which are able to "think" for fast calculations, it is still useful when you have to check if the move that player is trying to make is correct.

Posible Bitboard:

```
public class BitBoard
{
    public static final int P = 0;
    public static final int N = 2;
    public static final int B = 4;
    public static final int R = 6;
    public static final int Q = 8;
    public static final int K = 10;

    public static final int p = 1;
    public static final int n = 3;
    public static final int b = 5;
    public static final int r = 7;
    public static final int q = 9;
    public static final int k = 11;

    // empty field
    public static final int empty = 12;

    // number of pieces , squares
    public static final int nPieces = 12;
    public static final int nSquares = 64;

    public static final int whitePieces = 12;
    public static final int blackPieces = 13;
    public static final int nBoards = 14;

    public static long squareBits[];

    // static member initialization
    static
    {
        squareBits = new long[64];
        long square = 1;
        square = square << 8 * 8 - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            squareBits[i] = square >>> i;
        }
    }

    long bitBoards[];

    public BitBoard() {
        bitBoards = new long[nBoards];
    }

    public boolean initBoard()
    {
        // Put the pieces on the board
        EmptyBoard();
        addPiece(0, r);
        addPiece(1, n);
        addPiece(2, b);
        addPiece(3, q);
        addPiece(4, k);
        addPiece(5, b);
        addPiece(6, n);
        addPiece(7, r);
        for (int i = 8; i < 16; i++) {
            addPiece(i, p);
        }

        for (int i = 48; i < 56; i++) {
            addPiece(i, P);
        }
        addPiece(56, R);
        addPiece(57, N);
        addPiece(58, B);
        addPiece(59, Q);
        addPiece(60, K);
        addPiece(61, B);
        addPiece(62, N);
        addPiece(63, R);

        return true;
    }

    public boolean addPiece(int whichSquare, int whichPiece)
    {
        bitBoards[whichPiece] |= squareBits[whichSquare];
        bitBoards[nPieces + (whichPiece % 2)] |= squareBits[whichSquare];
        return true;
    }

    private boolean removePiece(int whichSquare, int whichPiece)
    {
        bitBoards[whichPiece] ^= squareBits[whichSquare];
        bitBoards[nPieces + (whichPiece % 2)] ^= squareBits[whichSquare];
        return true;
    }

    private boolean EmptyBoard()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nBoards; i++)
        {
            bitBoards[i] = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After considering your problem, and knowing the problem domain, I would actually suggest the following...

In your class `Panel` implement a function `int hasMass()` as follows...

```
public int hasMass() {
  return 0;
}
```

In your class `Piece` override that function as follows...

```
public int hasMass() {
  if (isWhite()) // white pieces are negative. 
    return -1;
  return 1; // black pieces positive.
}
```

Now you can check if the square has a piece, whether another given piece could take it... (because they have opposite polarity)... e.g. mass + mass == 0 means a capture, != 0 means the panel was empty. And of course an absolute value of 2 (for mass) would mean the move was illegal.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep a structure of the pieces separate from the rendered board.

For example, I would make the chess pieces pure models w/o knowledge of hit they're rendered.

```
Pieces (baseclass)
 +- Pawn
 +- Knight
 +- King
 +- Queen
 +- ..etc
```

This will allow you to keep an array of Pieces only, where empty squares are null.

For simplicity sake, I'd just have a matrix of peices:

```
Peices[][] board = new Pieces[8][8];
```

(of course an initialization method to traverse your 'board' and populate the board w/ the initial positions)

I would then have a visible board constructed of JPanels;  a class called "Chess" to manage game;  and the actual rendering of the tile/panel in the move function.  Imagine:

```
// what a move might look like when initializing your panels
piece = board [0][0];
Chess.move(piece, 0 ,0);  //responsible for clearing the old panel and rendering the panel at target location.
```

When the user interacts w/ your game..they click your panels..which will give you the panel coordinates.  You use the same coordinates w/ your 'board' to determine what the piece is..how it can move etc..

Something like that...

I would just represent the game board using objects...for simplicity.  Easiest to understand..and besides..computers are plenty fast now.

Comment: Yes completely agree. Any advice on how to go about this? Maybe an int or string array to store the board setup? Then match an appropriate JPanel to each element of the array?

Answer (score 0):

OK, ill start by throwing away the option of setting null to indicate that place is empty (you can do it ofc but using the `Empty` class is just 'better' in a way).

So let's say you have array of `Panel`s representing your game board:

```
Panel[][] board;
```

Now for ilustration, how your class hierarchy could look like:

```
abstract class Panel extends JPanel { ... }

class Empty extends Panel { ... }

abstract class Piece extends Panel { ... }

class Pawn extends Piece { ... }

...
```

> My Panel class is my Empty class is it not?

Not sure if i understand you, but let's have a look on what `extends` means exactly: in the show nmodel **every Piece is also a Panel** or **every Pawn is also a Piece**, so every Pawn can do all the same things as Piece (for example, 4 is complex number as well as natural number or real number, so in a way, you could say that *real numbers extend complex numbers*, since *every real number is also a complex number*)

So now you can have some nice abstract `getTexture()` method declared in `Panel` implemenented in `Empty` class and in all `Piece` subclasses, and when drawing a `Panel`, you dont need to look if it is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating (I assume) almost identical classes for each piece (Rook, Pawn, Queen etc.), you could just keep the original `Piece` class, make it non abstract and add a `PieceType` field to it. `PieceType` is just an `enum` that tells what type of piece (if any) is placed there. Instead of using `instanceof`, now you can check using `panels[i][j].getType() == PieceType.ROOK`. At least that's what I'm doing in my implementation :)

I'm also using `JLabel` instead of `JPanel` for my 8x8 board.

Comment: The classes are not going to be identical, each class will have methods for making moves

Comment: It's best practice to separate UI code from logic. That means placing the movement code (and check logic, en passant etc) outside the panels and keep the panels just for displaying whatever piece (if any) is there. But it's up to you. Have a look at MVC (Model-View-Controler) pattern if you want.